# SQL join 2 tables, query 1st with condition from 2nd

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 2 tables:

Downtime Categories:
`CatID ----- CatName ----- SiteID`

Downtimes:
`DtID ----- DtName ----- CatID`

How do I create a query so I can pull all of the records from Downtimes where the SiteID from Downtime Categories = x?

I don't know how to word this search to get what I need, I have tried all the Joins but none of them give me what I'm after

Any help would be appreciated, thanks

Edit:
I have tried all variants of the below answers but none of them worked... copying one into SMS and running it now worked first time :(
I must have had a typo somewhere...stupid...
Thanks for the replies

Comment: Please show what you've tried.

Comment: Do you want all records from downtimes even when an entry in downtime categories doesn't exist OR only those with a downtime category of "X"

Comment: @Prospector: Where the EF comes here?

Comment: Have a look at [Using Inner Joins](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa213234%28v=sql.80%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this

```
SELECT D.CatID ,D.CatName ,D.SiteID
FROM Downtimes D INNER JOIN DowntimesCategories DC
    ON D.CatID = DC.CatID
WHERE DC.SiteID = put your id here
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT D.* FROM
DOWNTIMES D INNER JOIN DOWNTIMECATEGORIES DC ON (D.CATID = DC.CATID)
WHERE DC.SiteID = X
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT T1.CatID
      ,T1.CatName
      ,T1.SiteID
FROM Downtimes AS T1
INNER JOIN DowntimesCategories AS T2
    ON T1.CatID = T2.CatID
WHERE T2.SiteID = X
```

Answer (score 1):

Try Inner join as below:

```
SELECT *
FROM DOWNTIME_CATEGORIES DC INNER JOIN DOWNTIME D
ON D.CatId = DC.CatID
WHERE DC.SiteID = 'X'
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks Like simple `INNER JOIN` is what you need

```
SELECT *
FROM   Downtime_Categories DC
       JOIN Downtimes D
         ON DC.CatID = D.CatID
            AND DC.SiteID = 'x'
```

Comment: @xQbert then what does this means `where the SiteID from Downtime Categories = x`

Answer (score 1):

This is what I came up with:

```
Select d.*
From Downtime d
Inner Join DowntimeCategories dc On dc.CategoryId = d.CategoryId
  And dc.SiteId = x
```